# DirectoryIndex ignored by Django Webapplication

Tags: python, django, static-files

Hey there,
i'm using an Q+A script that is build with python and django. My problem is that i want to serve some static files i placed in a certain directory. That works basically. My problem is if someone calls http://domains.com/static/sub1/ the content of this directory is shown as a list. I want that if you type this URL the index.html is serverd automatically. For that purpose i edited my .htaccess file and used the DirectoryIndex option. Seems like Django is ignoring that totally. Can anyone help?

Comment: Wait - are you serving those files through Django or Apache?

Comment: Then why are you mucking around with .htaccess? That's for Apache.

Comment: Yes, i know but i thought when i tell django to serve them in a static way i can place a .htaccess in the subdirectory and i will work. Anyways, how can i tell Django to use DirectoryIndex?

Answer (score 0):

```
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            'show_indexs': True,
        }),
    )
```